# Sphere as a countable collection of Circles

Tags: general-topology

The obvious answer is to use the Baire Category Theorem and show that it is impossible to write $S_2$ as the countable union of Circles. I wish to present a more intuitive, straight forward, argument that doesn't use this powerful theorem. I ask for feedback on the following argument.

Let $C=\{C_1,C_2,C_3,\ldots\}$ be a collection of circles on $S_2$. Since $C_1$ is a circle on $S_2$, then there must exist a compact spot (a circle with interior), $A_1$, on $S_2$ that doesn't intersection $C_1$. Since $A_1$ is a spot and $C_2$ is a circle, then again, there must exist a compact spot, $A_2$, where $A_2\subseteq A_1$ and $A_2$ do not intersect $C_2$. We can continue in this fashion and define a sequence $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ of compact sets such that $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$ and $A_n\cap C_n=\emptyset$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n\not=\emptyset$, then there are points on $S_2$ that are not in $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} C_n$.

I doubt this is a new argument for this famous problem. Could someone point me to a source?

Comment: This is basically reproving the Baire theorem for locally compact spaces. It's the standard argument (essentially) to see that a locally compact Hausdorff space is Baire.

Comment: That sounds like what I was thinking. Thanks.

Comment: A simple cardinality argument works. Let $P$ be the set of centres of the circles $C_n$. $P$ is countable, so there is a point $x\in S_2\setminus P$; let $C$ be any circle in $S_2$ with centre $x$. Clearly $C$ is distinct from each of the circles $C_n$, and any two distinct circles in $S_2$ intersect in at most two points, so $$C\cap\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}C_n=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}(C\cap C_n)$$ is the union of countably many finite sets and is therefore countable. And $C$ is uncountable, so $C\nsubseteq\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}C_n$ and hence $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}C_n\subsetneqq S_2$.